# after adding dynamic class how to check the class is existing using jquery

Tags: jquery

here is my Question,

I have added a class to a 'div' using jquery like this,

```
$('.myClass').addClass('active')
```

after adding this class I want to check whether 'active' is existing or not

for that I have written like this

```
if( $('.myClass').hasClass('active')) {
    alert('active');
}
```

But this is not working somebody please help me. And help will be really appreciated. 
thank you.

Comment: It's not myclass change it to myClass : class name is case sensitive.

Comment: Please have the courtesy to go through your questions and accept answers where appropriate. If the Stack Overflow community are generous enough to help you, you should at least acknowledge it.

Comment: I am sorry It was a typo mistake I have written my code properly.
but still it is not getting

Comment: Code looks good. can you show jsfiddle where it is not working?

Comment: There is no problem then, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uKaUD/) is your exact code in action

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in  the selector (jquery is case sensitive) change `myclass` to `myClass` like this:

```
$('.myClass').addClass('active');
if( $('.myClass').hasClass('active')) {
    alert('active');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ALt8A/)**

Answer (score 0):

class Names are `case sensitive` .You used `myClass` instead of `myclass`

```
if( $('.myClass').hasClass('active')) {
        alert('active');
    }
```

[**Case Sensitivity in class and id Names**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Case_Sensitivity_in_class_and_id_Names)